# How to detect a Wacom Intuos5 tablet in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, graphics-tablet

I have an Intuos5 drawing tablet that I'd like to use under Linux. Under Windows it runs fine, but I can't get it to work in Linux (using Mint 11).

lsusb shows that it is known as a USB device:

```
$ lsusb | grep Wacom
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 056a:002a Wacom Co., Ltd
```

It doesn't appear in the results of an `xinput list` command.

apt-get tells me that `xserver-xorg-input-wacom` is already installed, and my system is up to date. The config file for wacom devices (`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-wacom.conf`) exists and is still set to defaults.

What else should I try to get Mint to detect the tablet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Intuous5 is supported only in the newest wacom drivers and needs a 3.4 linux kernel. You can wait it out till Mint catches up or look into PPAs or rolling your own kernel for mint. 
See here: http://scottlinux.com/2011/07/15/how-to-compile-your-own-kernel-in-ubuntu-debian-mint/

While rolling your own kernel will work, it will probably require some upkeep and maintenance. It's up to you.

Here's the closed issue for intuos5 support: 
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3498470&group_id=69596&atid=525124

Comment: Yeah, I ended up finding some kernel patch emails that looked like it might not be up to date yet. Thanks for the tips.